# How to move 50GB RDBMS data into hadoop and process it? What is the minimum hardware requirement for process 50GB data by using hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to move 50GB RDBMS data into hadoop and process it?
 What is the minimum hardware requirement for process 50GB data by using hadoop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache Scoop](https://sqoop.apache.org) for importing data into Hadoop from RDBMS.
Regarding the minimum hardware - it all depends upon the storage you want to maintain and process in Hadoop cluster and the type of workload you will be running.

For general recommendation on sizing of Hadoop clusters you can refer [here](https://0x0fff.com/hadoop-cluster-sizing/) and some approximate example sizing calculation [here](https://data-flair.training/forums/topic/hadoop-cluster-hardware-planning-and-provisioning/).

Comment: For storing RDBMS data which is better to use HDFS or HIVE

Comment: @NaveenKumar Hive isn't the storage layer. It requires HDFS